# How to use my a property as a model

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

My MVC site works fine, it reads the data from EF and displays on page. I now have to add a "refine your search" section where customers can filter their results...

I have a horrible feeling my approach is wrong, if so, please do let me know!

My model looks like

```
using bconn.bll;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace bconn.ui.Models
{
    public class BoardToBoard
    {
        private bconnEntities _dataContext = new bconnEntities();

        public IEnumerable<bll.BoardToBoard> BoardToBoardConnectors 
        {
            set { }
            get
            {
                return _dataContext.BoardToBoards.ToList();
            }
        }
        public IEnumerable<bll.BoardToBoard> BoardToBoardSearch 
        {
            get{}
        }
    }
}
```

And my View:

```
@model bconn.ui.Models.BoardToBoard

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Test";
}

<table>

@foreach (var item in Model.BoardToBoardConnectors) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayTextFor(Model.BoardToBoardConnectors.Select(a=> a.Gender)) //FAULT
        </td>
    </tr>
}    
</table>
```

The issue I have, is the DisplayTextFor expects a  `System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<BoardToBoard,TResult>>)`

The problem is, I'm not using the class (BoardToBoard), I'm only using a property of BoardToBoard (BoardToBoardConnector), as shown in the foreach statement.

How can I use the DispalyTextFor for a property of the class? I assume I've miss understood the requirements of MVC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I would go:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.BoardToBoardConnectors) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayTextFor(m => item.Gender)
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

You can use `DisplayTextFor` for DataAnnotation formattings and sintax would be close to properties from `Model` you used to (`@Html.DisplayTextFor(m => m.Title)`).

Comment: you have to enter `(m => item.` to access them `item` properties.

Answer (score 1):

Do you need the DisplayTextFor?  Can you just do something like this?

```
@foreach (var item in Model.BoardToBoardConnectors) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            item.Gender
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

or this:

```
@for(int i = 0; i < Model.BoardToBoardConnectors.Count; i++ ) 
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayTextFor(m=>m.BoardToBoardConnectors[i].Gender) 
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```